# CSS HTML Floating issue with div's

Tags: html, css

I'm running into some issues with HTML / CSS. I want to float a number off divs after each other. But the last div in line doesn't float how I want it. It's a litte difficult to explain so I placed my code on JSFiddle:

In basic, my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="product-image"></div>
    <div class="product-title"></div>
    <div class="product-description"></div>
    <div class="product-spec"></div>
    <div class="product-offer"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Full example including CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/6r46B/

Below an image with these div's and how I want them to align:
[image]

The issue here is that the div `.product-offer` is floating right of the div `.product-spec`. But I want it all the way up. How would I do that?

PS: This part will be used in a responsive design. This will be the wide example.

Comment: To start with there is no such **element** as `link` that can be used in the `body` and you have random tags and closing tags in your HTML. In fact your structure is pretty weird as it is.

Comment: Have your floated elements first: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/6r46B/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D, the weird things you see are I think the schema.org microdata. I might not have worked that out perfectly. However, thats not the point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make product-offer the first element in the order of your DIVs to take precedence in the float-order.

Comment: Great! So simple, I just didn't see it! Thanks! Now I can try making it responsive!