# Rearranging html for responsive design

Tags: html, css

Yesterday I asked help for a html design where I could get the floating div's right. I got the right answer on that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369456/css-html-floating-issue-with-divs/23369586#23369586), thanks for that. Now I'm trying to use that same HTML in a responsive design. And again I'm running stuck. I need to change the order of the HTML to get the design working in the different responsive sizes. Therefore I probably need javascript and I don't believe that's how it should be done.

My basis HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="box box-1">box 1</div>
  <div class="box box-2">box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">box 3</div>
  <div class="box box-4">box 4</div>
  <div class="box box-5">box 5</div>
</div>
```

There are 3 different responsive sized, which are shown in this image:
[image]

I posted the code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjomb/right/). You can move the devider in the middle to resize the window and see what happens.

Like i said, in my opinion I need to rearrange the HTML. For the `min-width: 757px` I think I need to move the div `box-1` behind `box-5`. 
And for `max-width: 756px` I also need to move `box-3` in front of `box-1`. How can should I do this, without using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to edit your code and it seems to work

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufiso

Comment: Good @Mir! I hate the absolute position in media queries.  There will be problems with the position on mobile devices?

Comment: @Luiggi I actually hate using position at all, and avoid it when possible. In this case there is the need to get elements out of the dom flow. Perhaps a float will work too. I don't think this can cause problems on mobile, but only testing will clear this doubt.

Comment: I implemented your code into the real design and I must say, it works like a charm!!! Really great. Tested it on multiple devices (smartphones / tablets) and no issues at all with the positioning! GREAT and many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can do it with **flow-from and flow-into** CSS rules.

I hope it is your solution, if you can't, try with jQuery.

w3c info: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions-1/#regions

Comment: At the moment I'm working out an example where I position each div. I will also have a look at your suggestion! Thanks